# For loop that will give me objects at index: 0,1 then 1,2 then 2,3 then 3,4 following this pattern until array count?

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop

I've been trying to get these results for a while now.. I can't seem to figure it out. Anyone know how to go about doing this?

I'm trying to compare two objects to each other from the beginning of my array, to the end, in that sequence.

Tilo's Solution:

```
        for (int i=1; i<[tempRightArray count]; i++) {
            UIImageView* letterA = [tempRightArray objectAtIndex:i-1];
            UIImageView* letterB = [tempRightArray objectAtIndex:i];

            NSLog(@"LetterA: %@",letterA);
            NSLog(@"LetterB: %@",letterB);

            //Distance between right side of Touched piece and Left side of new piece == Touch on Right
            CGPoint midPointRightSidePiece = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(letterA.frame), CGRectGetMidY(letterA.frame));
            CGPoint midPointLeftSidepiece = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(letterB.frame), CGRectGetMidY(letterB.frame));
            CGFloat distance = DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(midPointLeftSidepiece, midPointRightSidePiece);

            NSLog(@"Distance: %f",distance);

        }
```

Updated with Pauls block solution:

```
    [tempRightArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if (idx > 0) {

            UIImageView *letterB = (UIImageView*)obj;

            id obj2 = [tempRightArray objectAtIndex:--idx]; // idx is the index of obj again given to you by the block args

            UIImageView *letterA = (UIImageView*)obj2;

            NSLog(@"LetterA: %@",letterA);
            NSLog(@"LetterB: %@",letterB);

            //Distance between right side of Touched piece and Left side of new piece == Touch on Right
            CGPoint midPointRightSidePiece = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(letterA.frame), CGRectGetMidY(letterA.frame));
            CGPoint midPointLeftSidepiece = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(letterB.frame), CGRectGetMidY(letterB.frame));
            CGFloat distance = DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(midPointLeftSidepiece, midPointRightSidePiece);

            NSLog(@"Distance: %f",distance);

        }

    }];
```

Comment: If you are iterating a collection (e.g. NSArray...) you should consider FastEnumeration as a safer option to setting up for loops manually to avoid off by one errors and they check that what you are enumerating is not being manipulated underneath you. just something to consider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i=1; i<[myArray count]; i++) {
  id obj1 = [myArray objectAtIndex:i-1];
  id obj2 = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];

  [self compare:obj1 to:obj2];
}
```

Comment: If I understood the question, it will does exactly what he wants. Apart from that, it will not go beyond (see edit).

Comment: Why not start with i=1 so you don't have to do subtraction on possibly every iteration of the loop?

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much man. And thanks to everyone else who helped. <3 I hate to admit it, but I've been trying this for a couple hours now.. Using for loops inside for loops with continues and breaks.. I never expected it to be so easy for some. ;)

EDIT: Jim was right, this did go beyond array.  index 9 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
  NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"b", @"c", @"d", nil];

  [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    if (idx > 0) {
      // obj  = the current element in the array. Given to you by the block args
      id obj2 = [array objectAtIndex:--idx]; // idx is the index of obj again given to you by the block args

      // Do whatever comparison you want between obj and obj2
      // ...
    }

  }];
```

Don't be scared by the syntax its pretty simple. The current object is `obj` and the index of that object in the array is `idx`.

Comment: With this, am I supposed to be able to compare two UIImageViews? I can't figure out how to translate your code to do that. Tilo's solution allowed me to do so quite easily. Is there a way with the above code to compare properties of imageviews @index 0 and 1, then 1 and 2, then 2 and 3, till the end? I updated my question with Tilos loop.

Comment: Thanks man. This works great. (I just had to switch obj1 and 2 around. While I don't fully understand blocks yet, I did get the same exact results using your solution. I already marked Tilo's as the answer though.. So I'm not sure what to do? I'm probably going to stick with your solution.

Comment: A lot of new API's use blocks and they are pretty handy, so it's worth getting into using them. Check the Apple docs they have some good guides on using them

Comment: Way too elaborate for the problem at hand.

Comment: How is it too elaborate? It's safer than setting up the for loop manually and blocks are becoming a more frequently used language feature.

Answer (score 0):

Start the for loop with your index at one. Stop when the index is greater than or equal to array count. Compare item at index and at index - 1;

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < array_count - 1; i++) {
   x = array[i];
   y = array[i + 1];
   /* do something with x and y */
}
```

Where `array` is the array, `array_count` is the length of `array`, `x` and `y` are declared as the same type as the elements stored in `array`. Is this what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that Objective-C is a superset of C.  Anything you can do in C, you can still do in Obj-C.

You probably weren't aware of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). You can execute multiple operations in each clause of a `for(;;)` loop.

```
NSUInteger limit, i, j;

for(limit = [array count], i = 0, j = 1; j <= limit; i++, j++)
  {
  //  i and j will increment until j hits the limit.   
  // do whatever you want with [array objectAtIndex:i] and [array objectAtIndex:j] in here.
  }
```